# Recording video in landscape with portrait view

Tags: android, android-videoview

What I want to do is to record the video in landscape with Android device portrait.
I have tried following, but it didn't work.

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

When I check the video recorded, it is taken in portrait.

Is it possible to take landscape video with Android portrait?

--EDIT--

If I use setDisplayOrientation(0), then I get first one.
If I use setDisplayOrientation(90), then I get second one.
What I want is the last one.

[image: setDisplayOrientation(0)]
[image: setDisplayOrientation(90)]
[image: what I want]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. I actually ran into this problem a while ago. You should get the desired result if you don't set:

```
    // Tags video with a 90° in order to tell the phone how to display it
    recorder.setOrientationHint(90);
```

So if you don't use this method, you should record in portrait and view in landscape. Are you using this method? If not I'm not sure what's up, maybe you could use it to change the orientation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also tried removing it, but the direction is wrong. I edited my question.