# How to make output video landscape mode when recording video in portrait mode?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

For some reason, I want video has fixed resolution in landscape whether i recorded in portrait mode or landscape mode. like this picture:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BSgo.jpg)

I try mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640,480) to set fixed resolution for my videos. But the output video still in 480x640. [output video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibZeF.png)

```java
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(camcorderProfile.fileFormat);
if (enableAudio) {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(camcorderProfile.audioCodec);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(camcorderProfile.audioBitRate);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(camcorderProfile.audioSampleRate);
}
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(camcorderProfile.videoCodec);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(camcorderProfile.videoBitRate);
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(
        640, 480);
```

My expectation is when i record video in portrait mode the output video has fixed resolution.
Edit: I found a similar questions in here but still have expected answer. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731784/recording-video-in-landscape-with-portrait-view)

in Ios i use AVMutableVideoComposition to convert my video after recorded. Is there anyway to convert video like this in Android

```swift
    let vComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    vComp.renderSize = CGSize(width: CustomConsts.SAVE_WIDTH, height: CustomConsts.SAVE_HEIGHT)
    vComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(CustomConsts.SAVE_FRAME_RATE))                    // fps

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: vTrack.timeRange.duration)


    let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: vTrack)
    var videoSize = vTrack.naturalSize
    videoSize = CGSize(width: videoSize.height, height: videoSize.width)
    let ratio = CGFloat(CustomConsts.SAVE_WIDTH) / videoSize.width
    let resizedVideoSize = CGSize(width: videoSize.width * ratio, height: videoSize.height * ratio)
    let t1 = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * CGFloat.pi / 180)  
    let t2 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: ratio, y: ratio)
    let t3 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: resizedVideoSize.width, y: -(resizedVideoSize.height - CGFloat(CustomConsts.SAVE_HEIGHT)) / 2)
    transformer.setTransform(t1.concatenating(t2).concatenating(t3), at: CMTime.zero)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
    vComp.instructions = [instruction]
```

Comment: By `mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);`, you are cropping the video. Not changing its size

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal is there any way to convert video recorded to expected resolution, My team already convert the video from 1280x720 to 640x480 in IOS, but i don't know how to convert in android